# How do I get the contents of temp file through a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

index.html.erb

```
= form_for :file_upload, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
      = f.label :uploaded_file, 'Upload your file.'
      = f.file_field :uploaded_file
      = f.submit "Load new dictionary"
```

Model

```
def file_upload
    file = Tempfile.new(params[:uploaded_file])
    begin
        @contents = file
    ensure
        file.close
        file.unlink   # deletes the temp file
    end
end
```

Index

```
def index
    @contents
end
```

But nothing is getting printed in my page after I upload a file `= @contents`

Comment: how did you get `params[:uploaded_file]` into your model? that looks like controller code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `file.read` to read the content of the uploaded file:

```
def file_upload
  @contents = params[:uploaded_file].read
  # save content somewhere
end
```

Comment: How can i send the contents back to the index

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix the problem is to define the `file_upload` as a class method and call that method in the controller.

index.html.erb

```
= form_for :index, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
      = f.label :uploaded_file, 'Upload your file.'
      = f.file_field :uploaded_file
      = f.submit "Load new dictionary"
```

Model

```
def self.file_upload uploaded_file
  begin  
    file = Tempfile.new(uploaded_file, '/some/other/path')        
    returning File.open(file.path, "w") do |f|
      f.write file.read
      f.close
    end        
  ensure
    file.close
    file.unlink   # deletes the temp file
  end

end
```

Controller

```
def index
  if request.post?  
    @contents = Model.file_upload(params[:uploaded_file])
  end
end
```

You'll need to apply sanity checks and stuff. Now that `@contents` is defined in the Controller, you can use it in the View.